# Python regex with unicode strings

Tags: python, regex, unicode

Could not match unicode string in python 2.7.
expected result 749130

```
>>> print match("\d+", u'\ufeff749130'.encode('utf-8'))
None
>>> print match("\d+", u'\ufeff749130')
None
>>> print match("\d+", u'\ufeff749130'.decode('utf-8'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
....
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufeff' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: `match` matches from the beginning of the string.  Use `search`.

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. What do want to do with the code?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No need to use `str.decode` on a unicode string. As stated in the comments, you may want to use `search` because `match` only matches from the beginning of the target string.

```
>>> print search("\d+", u'\ufeff749130').group()
749130
```